# Sunburst Nivo Plot the only one not displaying, no errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, visualization, nivo-react

I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wYpCWwD1oz0) tutorial to get an intro to React and everything works as intended.
So I tried to add another of the Nivo plots, *sunburst*, following the same method.

My App.js imports this new scene
[image: sunburst import in App.js]

It also as the route set up
[image: sunburst route add in App.js]

I've made a sunburst.jsx scene file
[image: sunburst.jsx scene file]

And, just like the pie component,
[image: pie component]

A SunburstChart.jsx component following the same formula, with mock data from nivo.

[image: start of mock data]

```
import { ResponsiveSunburst } from "@nivo/sunburst";
//import { tokens } from "../theme";
//import { useTheme } from "@mui/material";
import { mockSunburstData as data } from "../data/mockData";

const SunburstChart = () => {
  //const theme = useTheme();
  //const colors = tokens(theme.palette.mode);
  return (
    <ResponsiveSunburst
    data={data}
    margin={{ top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10 }}
    id="name"
    value="loc"
    cornerRadius={2}
    borderColor={{ theme: 'background' }}
    colors={{ scheme: 'nivo' }}
    childColor={{
        from: 'color',
        modifiers: [
            [
                'brighter',
                0.1
            ]
        ]
    }}
    enableArcLabels={true}
    arcLabelsSkipAngle={10}
    arcLabelsTextColor={{
        from: 'color',
        modifiers: [
            [
                'darker',
                1.4
            ]
        ]
    }}
    />
  );
};

export default SunburstChart;
```

As it is, I get no errors. But I also get a blank background where I should get my sunburst chart.

[image: pie chart showing up correctly]

vs

[image: sunburst chart not showing]

I'm at a loss and it compiles with no errors, so I have no idea where the bug is.

I have tried changing the code within the component definition, as the tutorial modifies a bit what the nivo website outputs, but no dice. I've replaced the Sunburst section with code for a simple Pie graph, that works fine : the problem isn't with routes or imports.

[image: pie graph inspect element]

[image: sunburst graph inspect element]

Nothing is rendered.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as well. Did you find a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Ok this answer is probably late, but I had the same issue myself and I found what what was causing the problem. By only specifying the height, the chart will for some reason automatically have width 0. If you also specify a width prop you should see the chart appear.

So for your innermost Box element:

```
<Box heigth="500px" width="500px">
  <SunbursrChart />
</Box>
```